# How do you attach a link to a created image in native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I came across this link
http://www.spielzeugz.de/html5/sticky-thing/

And tried to modify the image such that it can be clicked and redirect to a new link, but I can't make it work.

I see the image is created like this

```
N = new Image;
N.src = "src of image";
```

How can I create a 'a href' for the image that actually works?

NB: I tried

```
var L = document.createElement('a');
L.setAttribute('href',' ');
```

then

```
L.appendChild(N);
```

to no success.

Please help.

Comment: The method is called `.appendChild()`, not `.attachChild()`...

Comment: Yes appendChild, that didn't work

Comment: Why not just bind a click event listener to the image element, so that it will set the `window.location` to the link you want?

Comment: @Terry i've tried that and still not successful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work.

You just haven't appended the L object to anything so it won't appear.

```js
var N = new Image;
N.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQFxo.gif";

var L = document.createElement('a');
L.setAttribute('href', "https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQFxo.gif");
L.appendChild(N);

var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.appendChild(L);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: That would normally work as expected but does not answer for this exact situation. As I said, I'm referring to http://www.spielzeugz.de/html5/sticky-thing/ where the image N is passed through N.onload=Ib; a sticky effect function. I wud like my link to be attached to that image with the sticky effect.